# Exporting script output to CSV

Tags: powershell, active-directory, export-to-csv

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory 
Get-ADUser -SearchBase "OU=Users,DC=domain,DC=local" -Filter * | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host "User:" $_.Name -Foreground green
    Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $_.SamAccountName | ForEach-Object {
        Write-Host "Member Of:" $_.Name
    }
}
```

I have a script for getting all groups that a user is member of. Works correctly, but I can't export it to *.csv file. Output shows only in the PowerShell console. Any ideas what I exactly must add to script?

Comment: You should specify what output you expect, `Write-Host` stringifies output thereby tossing objects.

Comment: Take a look at [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv)

Comment: problem resolved, thanks to everyone for respond